# Adding the json array as a value to a json key using jackson in java

Tags: java, jackson

I'm getting a result from mongo db as

```
 [{"k1":"v1"},{"k2":"v2"}].
```

How to convert this result into

```
{"key" : [{"k1":"v1"},{"k2":"v2"}] }
```

using jackson.

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate class 'Key' with those members and in your main class have an array of Keys like

```
Key keys[];
```

then use the ObjectMapper to parse the values from mongo and write them back again to get the output.